# Disabling or gaming Sonos Crossfade

Tags: sonos

For short pieces of content, the Sonos crossfade feature is not desirable and ideally I'd like to be able to disable it for tracks with a small duration but this does not appear to be possible via the API. If it is not possible, I'd like to attempt to game it. Is crossfade implemented with a fixed duration or is there some kind of signal analysis going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is currently no way to adjust cross-fade through APIs.   It is done with a fixed timing of 12 seconds (6 seconds for the end of one track, 6 seconds for the beginning of next track).